# Should SessionHelper be replaced by controller concerns in Hartl's 3rd edition tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm currently reeding Hartl's 3rd edition tutorial for Rails and I'm wondering if the SessionsHelper should be replaced by a controller concerns.
I read that helpers are generally used to provide helper functions to views and in the case of SessionsHelper functions are used accross multiple class but never in views.

I think (but not sure) that concerns appear after this tutorial has been released, so my question ...

Should i try to replace the use of SessionsHelper with a controller concern.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Could you please provide links for this tutorial, quotations maybe and what does the SessionsHelper in that tutorial actually do? What is its interface? etc

Answer (score 0):

A `controller concern` is simply a Ruby module that you will include, by convention, only in controllers.

It is a good idea in general to regroup code that will be used in many places in a class or in a module.

If the logic for session management in that tutorial is used in many different controllers, it does make sense to create a module for that indeed (that you can put in the concern folder afterwards if you wish to do it the Rails Way).